# Change working directory

Tags: php, url, directory

Sorry for asking again, but I really need help. I have header.php in the root/lib which is including header_sub.php in the same directory. Normally files in root can directly include them by this code:

```
include_once('lib/header.php');
```

but now i have example.php in a sub-directory /blog, if i use these

```
include_once(../'lib/header.php');  or 
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/lib/header.php');  or 
include_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lib/header.php');
```

header_sub.php would not be included correctly.

Is there a way to include header.php and header_sub.php without modifying them?

Some body suggested to use these:

```
$oldcwd = getcwd(); // Save the old working directory
    chdir("../"); // Moves up a folder, so from /blog to /
    include("header.php"); // Include the file with the working directory as if the header file were being loaded directly, from it's folder
    chdir($oldcwd); // Set the working directory back to before
```

However, even i can see the current url is root directory after chdir(), it still includes this root/blog/lib......

Comment: you should try to be consistent and have a common path where these files can be accessed by. creating hacks to read around a bad design is not a solution.

Comment: is `/blog` sub directory of `/lib` ?

Comment: Hi Sergio, no it's not, they are all sub of root

Comment: Hi DevZerO, but these files are existing for ages.

Answer (score 2):

The path to the file you need depends on were you are calling the file.
Examples:

In `/root` calling file in `/root` -> `include_once('header.php');`
In `/root` calling file in `/root/lib` -> `include_once('lib/header.php');`
In `/root/lib` calling file in `/root` -> `include_once('../header.php');`
In `/root/blog` calling file in `/root/lib` -> `include_once(../lib/'header.php');`
In `/root/blog/css` calling file in `/root/lib` -> `include_once(../../lib/'header.php');`

If you do like this all path are relative and you can change the root folder and everything still works.

Another option is you have a file called "common.php" or "include.php" were you define path for some folders. This is useful if your site directory has many sub folders.